# How to create output directory when downloading source code GAE on mac

Tags: google-app-engine, directory, output

whenever I use directory /usr/local/bin/---- it shows error:couldn't create output directory. any tips?

Comment: Did you check the permissions?  What happens if you go to the /usr/local/bin directory and type `mkdir emptyFolder` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac OS X 10.11 El Capitan, the `/usr` directory is now protected by the operating system. `/usr/local` remains open, but if you don't have `/usr/local` (or it was deleted), it will be challenging to create it. Homebrew has good instructions on the subject: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/El_Capitan_and_Homebrew.md

If that's not the solution, please update your question with more information. For example, include the output of: `ls -ld /usr /usr/local /usr/local/bin`